# Writing one client for IOS and Android based devices

Tags: android, ios

This question was asked an year ago and I want to ask again as earlier the answer was not straightforward :-). I am hoping we have clarity on it now.

My question relates to best way to develop a single client for IOS and Android based devices for a simple data entry type application.The app will not use any  device specific features like GPS, Camera etc  The following is my understanding , feel free to correct or add:

1. HTML5/Javascript based client is best (ie from write once run everywhere perspective) so long as device has a connection to the central web server.
2. For native IOS/Android device clients I am not clear which SDK should be used. I need to have an offline data entry capability  in the client, just in case device is disconnected for later sync-up with server. Again I am looking for write once run everywhere type of client.
3. Is XML/RPC based interaction best way for device client to communicate with the central web server.
4. Asusming I develop an IOS based client for smartphone, what extra work is required to run it on the IPAD . I mean whether it can be done via (xml ?) config or will it require development separately.

Thanks in advance.
Sohail

Answer (score 1):

Go with phonegap. It's the best option for developing smartphone apps that are complaint with all sorts of mobile browsers. As far as frameworks concerned, you can choose snencha touch or jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

"Write one run everywhere" lefts html5 as the only option, any other solution can't do that, even html5 wrappers like phonegap or sencha requires platform-specific tools to pack it like an native app or create native plugins for it. Html5 app can be designed to able to work offline and store data locally.
I don't prefer xml/rpc for xml is heavy to parse and too much additional characters is added for xml form to transfer load, json is more light and popular.
To support ipad, you need create a set of ipad UI(usually another set of xib or storeboard). You can use same codes if the 2 sets of UIs are identical.

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2, If the app is that simple, why not just write it native in both os's so it will perform well?  We've seen our costs of maintenance be tremendously higher in apps that attempt WORE mentality and use stuff like Titanium and Sencha.

If you want simplicity, just making it a customized web page.

1. We've had great success with JSON based interaction using restful services.
2. iPad and Android tablets should both have their own custom graphic layouts that take advantage of the extended real estate.

Comment: can you suggest an SDK that will provide JSON/Restful framework ? Ideally I would like the SDK to provide an IOS/Android emulator as well. Thx